# Laravel Many-to-Many Relationship

Tags: many-to-many, laravel, laravel-3

I have two models `User` and `Role` i have turned off timestamps for both of them like so

```
public static $timestamps=false
```

and also i have removed the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns from both the tables(`users` & `roles`).

I also have a 3rd pivot table called `role_user` with 3 columns `id`,`user_id` and `role_id`

when i try find the role of a user i keep getting Column unknown `role_user.created_at` not found.`

Please Help am stuck with this problem. thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In laravel 3 pivot tables needs to have a time stamp. Either add this line to you migrations: $table->timestamps() or create the columns manually. I believe the column type is datetime for both the created_at and updated_at columns.

Comment: wow tnx for your quick reply...now everything is working perfectly...didn't know the timestamps were mandatory.

Comment: i have the same problem. Why do they need the timestamps? Seems very anti-laravel to insist on something being in place

Comment: In laravel 4 (releases may 28), pivot tables are not assumed to have timestamp columns. they need to be specified `return $this->belongsToMany('Role')->withTimestamps();`

Answer (score 0):

In pivot tables the timestamps are essential. The datatype for timestap is datetime.

Answer (score 0):

I have just had the same problem. Fixed it by adding:

```
Laravel\Database\Eloquent\Pivot::$timestamps = false;
```

to application/start.php